# Issue with clicking tow buttons at the same time

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities.
In activity_Second when user click button_right, activity_Second will destroy and activity_Third starts; 
again In activity_Second when user click button_left, activity_Second will destroy and activity_First starts.

Every thing is working fine until user click both buttons at the same time, then BANG , the app crashes.
Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem.

note: I need to destroy the activity_Second because it gets a couple of mediaplayers and as a result a lot of space and I need to release the memory.

here is the java code for activity_Second:

```
public class Second extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        right = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Third.class);
        left = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), First.class);
        ImageView button_left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_left);
        ImageView button_right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_right);

        button_left.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_right.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View item) {
        if(item.getId() == R.id.button_left)
        {
            left.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(left);
            this.onDestroy();
        }
        else if(item.getId() == R.id.button_right)
        {
            right.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(right);
            this.onDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: call `finish()` instead of `onDestroy()`.

Comment: @Zhuinden Thanks, I test it, but it still crashes! I even comment all the lines of releasing the media players but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this may help you,

```
public class Second extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        ImageView button_left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_left);
        ImageView button_right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_right);

        button_left.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_right.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View item) {
        if(item.getId() == R.id.button_left)
        {
            Intent left = new Intent(Second.this, First.class);
            left.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(left);

            finish();
        }
        else if(item.getId() == R.id.button_right)
        {
            Intent right = new Intent(Second.this, Third.class);
            right.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(right);

            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `ApplicationContext` causes problems? How come?